# NetworkError when attempting to fetch resource Passport ReactJS and ExpressJS : CORS

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, cors, passport.js

I have a front-end developed using React JS (http://localhost:3000/) and my backend using express JS (http://localhost:5000/)

**google Console details**

[image]

**React Login page : on click of login using Google**

```
  const _handleGoogleSignInClick = async () => {
        window.open("http://localhost:5000/socialauth/google", "_self");
    }
```

Express code

```
app.use(express.json());
app.use(cookieSession({
    name: "session",
    maxAge: 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000,
    keys:[keys.session.cookieKey]
}))

app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
app.use(
    cors({
      origin: "http://localhost:3000",
      methods: "GET,HEAD,PUT,PATCH,POST,DELETE",
      credentials: true
    })
  );

//routes
app.use(cors());
app.use("/auth", require("./routes/jwtAuth"));
app.use("/socialauth", socialAuth);

********************************************************
const CLIENT_HOME_PAGE_URL = "http://localhost:3000";

router.get('/google', passport.authenticate('google', { scope: ["profile"] }));
router.get('/google/callback', passport.authenticate('google', {
    successRedirect: CLIENT_HOME_PAGE_URL,
    failureRedirect: "/socialauth/login/failed"
}));

router.get("/login/success", (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.user);
    if (req.user) {
        res.json({ true});
    }
});
```

**Now that I have successfully authenticated users from Google, passport JS creates a session for the user and redirects users to front end where they again have to validate themselves. At this point, the front end tries to validate the user, the server successfully validates the user and returns true, but this is not captured by the front end. Hence the user cannot see the dashboard as the state remain false...**

```
fetch("http://localhost:5000/socialauth/login/success", {
          method: "GET",
          credentials: "include",
          headers: {
            Accept: "application/json",
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
            "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials": true
          }
        })
          .then(response => {
            if (response.status === 200) return response.json();
            throw new Error("failed to authenticate user");
          })
          .then(responseJson => {
            console.log("responseJson is -====", responseJson);
            setIsAuthenticated(true);
```

**the problem??**

On accessing  fetch("http://localhost:5000/socialauth/login/success" from the client side, i see that the server can successfully identify the user and returns true, but however on my client side i am unable to get the JSON response.

**ERROR DETAILS**

error is -==== TypeError: NetworkError when attempting to fetch resource. DesktopComponent.js:62
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at ‘http://localhost:5000/socialauth/login/success’. (Reason: Credential is not supported if the CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ is ‘*’)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT: issue was a `app.use(cors())` overwriting the

```
app.use(
    cors({
      origin: "http://localhost:3000",
      methods: "GET,HEAD,PUT,PATCH,POST,DELETE",
      credentials: true
    })
  )
```

which is necessary when using CORS with credentials

You can refer to [CORS credentials](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS/Errors/CORSNotSupportingCredentials)

It is basically because your client side is sending a request with `withCredentials` that you'll need to set to false (or else change the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` on the server side)

Comment: if front end = withCredentials is set to false, the server fails to identify the user.

Comment: I am not familiar with your environment and if there are constraints coming from the Google config, but there are other ways to identify users. You will need otherwise to change your Access-Control-Allow-Origin, it cannot be *: you need to specify the protocol + domain + port. For example:
```
var cors = require('cors');    
app.use(cors({credentials: true, origin: 'http://localhost:3000'}));
```

Comment: I have done this as well as you can see above in express code. . But still it fails.

Comment: OMG. That was the culprit.....IT worked man....Try to edit your comment. let me upvote for you. thanks a lot man.. I forgot to remove the app.use(cors()).